# find similar documents based on tags in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I try to use elastic search to my CMS to recommand 'related posts'
Currently, I use postgres to save posts.

Can elasticsearch find similar document?

How to find related posts based on tags, authors and more from the structured document below

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "Post1",
  authors : ["author1", "author2"],
  tags: ["Tag1", "Tag2", "Tag3"]
}
```

Comment: if you could could show us your ES mappings? ES can find, as long as your mapping is intact.

Comment: Yes you can do that using bool query, it has should property so if you add array of your tags in term query it will find what you want :)

Comment: Actually documentation has example you need https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

Comment: @volodymyr-bilyachat "Bool Query" is what i need! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I mention in comments for your  case ideal would be to use [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) in combination with should.

One thing to note it will work that more terms match higher score will be. In addition you should be aware that you could have problems with multiple words by default. So look at [keyword type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) and build analyzer to lowercase your tags if you need